# Memcached and php sessions problem

Tags: php, memcached

I have 2 servers running each one instance of repcached. Php is configured to save sessions there.

The 2 servers are replicated for redundancy

The problem is that I am doing some benchmarks with ab. Running

```
ad -n 10000 -c 500 http://mysite
```

I am getting some errors in the apache error log that 
    failed to write session data

Looking at the listen_disabled_num at both servers it is 0, so no connections are not served

By the way I have max connections set to 4096

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before when the session data was larger than Memcache's 1MB barrier. I solved it by compressing the session data before it was stored in Memcache.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
class SessionHandler {
    public $lifeTime;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->lifeTime = intval(ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime"));

        session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",".domain.com",false,true);
        session_name("SITESESSION");
        session_set_save_handler(array (&$this,"open"),array (&$this,"close"),array (&$this,"read"),array (&$this,"write"),array (&$this,"destroy"),array (&$this,"gc"));
        session_start();
    }

    public function open($savePath,$sessionName) {
        return true;
    }

    public function close() {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($sessionID) {
        # The default miss for MC is (bool) false, so return it
        return MC::get("userSession_{$sessionID}");
    }

    public function write($sessionID,$data) {
        # This is called upon script termination or when session_write_close() is called, which ever is first.
        return MC::set("userSession_{$sessionID}",$data,$this->lifeTime,true); # The last true sets it as compressed.
    }

    public function destroy($sessionID) {
        # Called when a user logs out...
        return MC::delete("userSession_{$sessionID}");
    }

    public function gc($maxlifetime) {
        # The MC keys expire on their own, no need to do anything here.
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi PureForm. Unfortunately, that's not my case as the session data are very small